# SWFUpload Examples/Information and Java

Tags: java, flash, file-upload

I built a couple working examples that upload an image to the server and display it on the page without refreshing. One approach was the iframe method, and the other was [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/) (version 3).

I wonder if anyone has an example using SWFUpload. I am not quite sure how it hooks into the server side code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, SWFUpload has always made the trick. I've been using it specially to be able to upload a bunch of files without to have to "browse" several times. It's easy to integrate server side as all you have to do is accept the incoming files as if they were uploaded via form. The only issue I've met so far is when you have to upload within the context of a server-session, there are workarounds though (sending SESSID via get, etc.).

In terms of examples I think you have all what you need in their [repository](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/downloads/list).